# Angular2 router.navigate refresh page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is how the routes and component look like:

> routes.config

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
   { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },   
   { path: 'users/new', component: NewUserComponent },    
];
```

> new-user.component

```
 addField(newName: string){
        this.items.push({ 
          name: newName,
      })
      this._router.navigate(['/users'])
```

Is Angular2 supposed to **refresh the page on router.navigate?**

**What else to use instead** of router.navigate to avoid any page refresh?

Here is the proof:
[image]

Comment: No, it's not. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Probably not, if it's not supposed to act like that, but i'll try.

Comment: At least we can investigate the full code and check if something is not right.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but i can't find any plunker running with RC3 router installed, and i've never done a plunker before. Do you happen to have one that i can edit?

Comment: That's what the link in my first comment is supposed to help with ;-)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You are probably calling the `router.navigate` function inside a click event.

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
    (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

And the save function being something like

```
save() {
    //Do stuff
    this._router.navigate(['/users', { id: userId } ]);
}
```

This works on IE11 and Edge browsers, but would reload the application in Chrome.

This is because of a missing `type` in the button element, if the button is inside a `<form></form>` Chrome will use 'submit' as it's default value. Causing a form submit when the button is clicked.

It's preferred to always set a `type` when using the `button` element
[See here:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

So changing the HTML to

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"
        (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Will make it work on all 3 browsers.

My previous solution also works, (By returning false it would prevent the default action. a.k.a. submitting the form) but I think the above one is preferred.

> Obsolete answer but kept for posterity:
>
> ```
> <button class="btn btn-default"
>         (click)="save(); false">Save</button>
> ```

Comment: Both solutions work fine, but the one you suggested makes more sense. So if i understand well the bottom line is ... never use `button type="submit"` in a SPA? :-D

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried to fix it with event.preventDefault() but this solution is much better.

Comment: hm, for me adding the false works as well, but would rather do it with the type... but don't have buttons, but regular links... and type="button" on regular links does not seem to do the trick

Comment: In my case component is reloading. ex:- Initially i am in rout-1 and modved to route-2, If i am come back to route1. that route1 component is reloading again(constructor is getting called) is that expected behaviour

Comment: Thankyou! I was facing this problem of navigation happening twice in Edge when router.navigate was called. I was trying other solutions. But your answer really explains why it was happening twice. This solution worked.

Comment: what about if we're mapping (keydown) in input form element though?? It behaves in the same way like we're submitting the form. I don't think type='button' applies there, does it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same effect (page refresh when navigating to details page) using a simple `<a href="/details/1"></a>` link.
The solution was to use the angular link: `<a [routerLink]="['/details', 1]"></a>`

Comment: [routerLink] indeed works, in my case I had logic to perform before nav so [routerLink] is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I know its simple method but you can also set this code to refresh route on success event after all operation finished.

> window.open('users', '_self');

It will reload and redirect to user page.

Answer (score 1):

For me works nice (from component code):

```
window.location.href = "/sth";
```

it automatically reloads page to given url part.

Answer (score 0):

This covers an AngularJS/Angular hybrid situation. I'm adding the answer because this question is one of the top results when you google angular router page reload issues. Hopefully it'll save somebody else time.

In my case I had a very simple Angular 2 (actually 5) route configuration that mostly worked except for one case where a link from one route to another would inexplicably cause a page reload. I had checked for all the usual suspects, form, submit button, etc.

It turned out that somewhere in an **AngularJS** component that was displayed at the time the link was clicked, there was an `ng-include`. The documentation warns about this for a reason I guess. Reshuffled the template so the `ng-include` could be changed to a `templateUrl` and all was well.