# Angular2/TypeScript - loading twice when using navigateByUrl to redirect component

Tags: typescript, navigation, components, angular2-routing

I want to implement the *login function* which the current component can be navigated to another component after clicking the login button.

My .ts and .html files are shown as follows

[login.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crxfz.png)

[login.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW6Bt.png)

The question is : when I use **npm start** to monitor the change, expiryPage(which is the target I want to redirect to ) since to be loaded twice.
The first time the component is loaded, the url looks like

`http://localhost:3000/expiryPage?`

and then the page will refresh soon that the url will be fixed, like

`http://localhost:3000/expiryPage`

It seems to work when using npm, but when I use a google chrome application **"Web Server"** to run the web, it gives me a `entry not found` on the page and the error messenge `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Is there any idea about this question? I have searched the solution for couple hours 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer from [Angular2 router.navigate refresh page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38144812/5717996)

Hope it helps who is in cart