# Angular 2, cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to substitute an anchor tag with a button tag to navigate to another route. As a result, I have a function that is called on click, which looks something like this:

```
submitReport (simpleOrDetailed : string) {
        this.router.navigate(['../ticket-list', simpleOrDetailed]);
}
```

I used to have it like this embedded in the HTML and it worked perfectly fine:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" [routerLink]="['../ticket-list', 'simple']" routerLinkActive="active"> Simple Report</a>
```

What's going on here? From my understanding, it should be doing the exact same thing.

**UPDATE**

I got it to match my route by replacing the body of the function with this 
(web-report is the parent component of the current component as well as the ticket-list component):

```
this.router.navigate(['web-report/ticket-list', simpleOrDetailed]);
```

However, this causes an unpleasant page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do relative navigation you need to add `relativeTo`

```
this.router.navigate([crisis.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I have tried the following to no avail:

`this.router.navigate(['../ticket-list',simpleOrDetailed , {relativeTo: this.route}]);`

Also:

`this.router.navigate(['../ticket-list',simpleOrDetailed , {relativeTo: this.route.parent}]);`

I am trying to go up a directory so that I can access the ticket list's component.

Comment: Well it seems this works: `  this.router.navigate(['../ticket-list', simpleOrDetailed], {relativeTo: this.route});` but I am still getting that awful page reload. If it's of any help, there are parameters related to an object I have in the url (which I did not intend on showing in there).

Comment: what is an umpleasant page reload?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thanks! Here is the post that helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120756/angular2-router-navigate-refresh-page

Comment: Glad to hear :)